# What are the optimum settings for uTorrent

Tags: windows, bittorrent

I am recently getting slow speeds for downloading torrents on uTorrent.
However when the speed is (1-3kBps) I stop the torrent and Start it again then the speed level climbs to the usual high level (100-200kBps) and gradually drops to (1-3kBps) speeds again .

What should be the optimum settings for

- Number of connections per torrent
- maximum number of connected peers
- Maximum number of upload slots per torrent
  and what ever settings that i need to change to improve the speed

Comment: this depends on your network connection, routers...

Comment: i use a 1.8Mbps HSPA connection(Dongle) which gives up to 230kBps Download speed

Answer (score 1):

1 Big tip I can give you:
 internet providers like to look in to your traffic and shape it.

Here in Belgium our providers they slow down traffic when they notice heavy torrent traffic going to or from your local network.

To prevent this you use encrypted peers only. this will encrypte the torrent sessions over ssl and your provider won't be able to look in what traffice is passing trough.

You should have following options:

> Off = don't use it
>   On = use it if possible
>   forced = only make connections with encrypted peers

I use the Second option as not all peers use encryption.

ps: maximum number of connected peers set it up to 100
in case you would have 30 encrypted and 30 non-encrypted peers you have plenty of room left for more peers.

Comment: currently i am using Forced encryption

Comment: Could you try to put on just ON
it could be there are no encrypted peers for the torrens you are searching for.